# ImagesLoaded.js won't work with Isotope and LazySizes

Tags: javascript, webpack, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope, imagesloaded

*I apologise if there **is** an answer out there, please point me towards the correct duplicate if so.*

- Isotope: https://isotope.metafizzy.co
- ImagesLoaded: https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/
- LazySizes: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

I'm trying to build a mini gallery which uses lazysizes for lazy-loading, isotope for sorting, and imagesLoaded to reflow the layout when a lazy image is loaded.

For some reason my imagesLoaded function won't update Isotope, but if I log the event and then manually run `iso.layout()` it DOES reflow the layout. Any ideas what's up?

```
import lazySizes from 'lazysizes';
const Isotope = window.Isotope = require("isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.js");
const imagesLoaded = window.imagesLoaded = require("imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js");

//.....

document.querySelectorAll(".content-gallery .medias").forEach(element => {
    const elem = element;

    const iso = new Isotope(elem, {
        itemSelector: ".media",
        layoutMode: "fitRows",
        percentPosition: true,
    });

    function reflow(){
        iso.layout();
    }

    imagesLoaded(elem)
        .on("progress", reflow)
        .on("always", reflow)
        .on("done", reflow)
        .on("fail", reflow)
        .on("lazyloaded", reflow)
        .on("load", reflow);

});
```

If I do a nasty `setInterval()` then isotope also relflows, so it appears there's something wrong with ImagesLoaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [imagesLoaded documentation](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com#vanilla-javascript) is misleading, you cannot use `.on` in native JS to listen for events, you must use `element.addEventListener()`.

Example:

```
function reflow(){
    iso.layout();
}

new imagesLoaded(elem);

elem.addEventListener("progress", reflow);
elem.addEventListener("always", reflow);
elem.addEventListener("done", reflow);
elem.addEventListener("fail", reflow);
elem.addEventListener("lazyloaded", reflow);
elem.addEventListener("load", reflow);
```